# How to register an Azure Resource Provider using Python

Tags: python, azure

I need help with automating a new subscription creation and one piece I needed to perform would be registering a resource provider. I can see this applicable from PowerShell but I am unable find the SDK module that can do this.

can someone point me to the SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely doable with `azure-mgmt-resource`, a few example around providers:

```
    self.resource_client.providers.unregister('Microsoft.Search')
    self.resource_client.providers.get('Microsoft.Search')

    result_list = self.resource_client.providers.list()
    for provider in result_list:
        self.resource_client.providers.register(provider.namespace)
        break
```

Doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/python/api/overview/azure/resources

(I work at MS in the SDK team)

Comment: That was great,  I looked all over that Class but was unable to find anything related to providers.

Do you happen to have a sample code If I want to use RestAPI, I can see only Powershell samples

Comment: Absolutely, RestAPI doc is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/providers

Answer (score 0):

Searched for the [azure python sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python) , no such method related to `Azure Resource Provider` could be found.

However, you could implement your requirements by [Provider REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/providers) with python code.

Comment: Thanks, was hoping for native in the SDK, I will go that route